# Determining a limit of a function doesnt match up

Tags: limits, functions, limits-without-lhopital

Consider this function

$$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac {x^3 - 8} {x-2}$$

Now what I've done is I've tried to alter the fraction to avoid division by zero. For the numerator, I've put it as this

$$ \frac {(x - 2)^3} {x-2} $$

After this I've simply gotten rid of the cube and the lower part of the fraction leaving me with this

$$(x-2)^2$$

And here I've applied the formula $$a^2 -2ab + b^2$$ And I than I put in 2 and I get as a result $$ x^2 +4x + 4$$
If i put in 2 now I get 16. Now the solutions say 12, but the solutions are notorius to be wrong more often than you would think.Is my solution correct? If not what am I doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Your problem is that $x^3-8$ is not the same as $(x-2)^3$. The correct factorization of the numerator (top of the fraction) is $(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)$.

Comment: The top of a fraction is the numerator and the bottom is the denominator.

Comment: Also you can directly plug in $x = 2$ in to $(x - 2)^2$, which yields 0 directly, without applying the quadratic formula.

Comment: Okay so I did the factorization wrong.What would be a good way to check if a factorization is correct. For example, if I applied the cubic formula to (x-2)^3 I should get x^3- 8,if I dont get that than the factorization was wrong?

Comment: Since \begin{align*} (x - 2)^2 & = (x - 2)(x - 2)\\ & = x(x - 2) - 2(x - 2)\\ & = x^2 - 2x - 2x + 4\\ & = x^2 - 4x + 4\end{align*} we obtain \begin{align*} (x - 2)^3 & = (x - 2)(x - 2)^2\\ & = (x - 2)(x^2 - 4x + 4)\\ & = x(x^2 - 4x + 4) - 2(x^2 - 4x + 4)\\ &  = x^3 - 4x^2 + 4x - 2x^2 + 8x - 8\\ & = x^3 - 6x^2 + 12x - 8\end{align*}

Comment: Notice that substituting $2$ into the expression gives you $0/0$, which suggests that the denominator $x - 2$ is a factor of the numerator $x^3 - 8$. If you did not know the difference of cubes formula $a^3 - b^3 = (a - b)(a^2 + ab + b^2)$, you could use polynomial division to simplify the expression.

Comment: Great comment thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$x^3-a^3\ne (x-a)^3$, except in characteristic $3$.

It can be much simpler to determine: $\frac{x^3-2^3}{x-2}$ is the rate of variation of the function $x^3$ from $x=2$, so the limit is its derivative $\:3x^2\bigr|_{x=2}=12$.